# Is this Why a Neutron can Decay Into a Proton, Electron and Electron Antineutrino?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, neutrons, weak-interaction

A neutron is udd, then an u-anti-u starts to exist close to the neutron. Then the one d and u change places forming an uud (proton) and anti-ud which decays to an electron and electron-antineutrino. Now it is my reasoning that since this process exists the process can be sidestepped so that a udd decays directly to a uud and electron and electron-antineutrino. Is this true?

Comment: Even if that is the case, why it matters/makes a difference? I think that what you describe is a beta decay: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why is it hard to tell: it's as explicit as I can make it. This process as stated makes exact the rule that a particle should decay to the same amount of quarks minus antiquarks.

Comment: It matters because then other processes may also be sidestepped.

Answer (score 2):

According to the theory of the weak interaction
the neutron ($udd$) changes directly to a proton ($uud$),
without involving any anti-quark ($\bar{u}$ or $\bar{d}$).

Quoting from [Wikipedia - W and Z bosons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_and_Z_bosons#W_bosons):

> Again, the neutron is not an elementary particle but a composite of
> an up quark and two down quarks ($udd$).
> It is in fact one of the down quarks that interacts in beta decay,
> turning into an up quark to form a proton ($uud$).
> At the most fundamental level, then, the weak force
> changes the flavour of a single quark:
> $$d \to u + W^−$$
> which is immediately followed by decay of the $W^−$ itself:
> $$W^− \to e^− + \bar{\nu}_e$$
> [image]
> <sub>The Feynman diagram for beta decay of a neutron into a proton,
> electron, and electron antineutrino via an intermediate $W^-$ boson</sub>

Comment: It looks that way, but the u-anti-u and anti-ud may just be unobservable.

Comment: My way is more palatable than a quark changing flavour.

Comment: My way explains why neutrons do not decay in a nucleus: there are no usable u-anti-u particles to cause it to decay (no space for them inside the nucleus).

Comment: If quark flavour conservation is ever proved this would invalidate the Wikipedia info.

Comment: Isn't quark flavor conservation implied by a strict version of charge conservation?